# Could not load type 'MongoDB.Bson.PreserveAttribute'

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, .net-framework-version, .net-4.7.2

I have this error when I updated my .NetFramework to 4.7.2 and I updated my MongoDb.Driver to 2.19.1. I have cleaned my references and the error still occurs.

[image: this is my error]

```
Could not load type 'MongoDB.Bson.PreserveAttribute' from assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.3.23, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MongoDB.Bson.PreserveAttribute' from assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.3.23, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) +197
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) +166
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) +156
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +612
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +149
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +199
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) +68
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +89
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +30
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +165
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +37
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +139
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +160
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +587
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +255
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +347

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'MongoDB.Bson.PreserveAttribute' from assembly 'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.3.23, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
```

I have updated all the projects to 4.7.2 and did the check uncheck method in the project solution in the configuration properties. I have resolved other issues but this one is a roadblock for me.

In addition: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe is at version 5.0.0 and I am using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.4

update: i have seen the issue. seems like my cleanup didn't really removed the unused reference since i have no option of clean unused reference, i removed the unused file in my project

[Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnf81.png)

Comment: don't paste links, use plain test instead

Comment: @dododo i am not allowed to post any image yet

Comment: But you can post text

Comment: @dododo there i have updated the error message

Comment: Can you include your `.csproj` file content (as text)?

Comment: How do you "clean your references"? When does this error occur? Locally or after deployment? Sounds like there's an old assembly somewhere, perhaps a transitive dependency (did you upgrade the package in all related projects and packages)?

Comment: i cleaned it when i tried uninstalling mongodb drivers (there is an option where you'll have to check uninstall even if there are references). everything runs smoothly when I upgraded to 4.7.2 but when i try to upgrade the mongodb driver and its dependencies to 2.19.1, then the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

> I updated my MongoDb.Driver to 2.19.1.

you should also update related nugets like `MongoDB.Bson` and `MongoDB.Driver.Core`

Comment: yes bson and core are already using version 2.19.1

Comment: sounds line no, based on the error message `'MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.4.3.23,`